# Docker - Import Json Docment Inside The Solr Core

Tags: json, docker, solr, docker-compose, dockerfile

I want to ask if there is a way to import Json document into the core from the docker file while creating the core, or if I can mount a pre-created core directory with the Json file already imported inside it.

An another method than import the document from Solr server page in `Documents` core tab and submit it.

This is the Solr part of my `docker-deploy.yml` file:

```
version: "3.2"
services:
  solr:
    image: solr:6.5
    ports:
     - "8983:8983"
    volumes:
      - solr_data:/opt/solr/server/solr/mycores
    entrypoint:
      - docker-entrypoint.sh
      - solr-precreate
      - MyCore
    networks:
      - analytics
```

Is there a way ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just have add and a bind to pre-created core with the Json data already imported inside it.

```
services:
  solr:
    image: solr:6.5
    ports:
     - "8983:8983"
    volumes:
      - solr_data:/opt/solr/server/solr
      - ./resources/participant:/opt/solr/server/solr/mycores
    networks:
      - analytics
```